# Moving an entire slice of data to another database using LINQ

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework

I have a database with many tables and constraints (but not much data). The database contains a few separate entities that are bound together by an ID directly or indirectly, as illustrated below:

[image]

My target is to move one entire slice of data (including data from all tables in the database) to another physical database in an easy and safe way. It's OK if it doesn't perform very well. In the above example, I would want to move the company with a certain Id as well as all employees of that company and all data related to the employees etc. through all the tables.

I want to do it with a safe compile-checked method, as I want to catch errors whenever I change my database.

The IDs in the database are mostly guids, but there are a few tables using auto incremented IDs.

**note**
The "Companies" table contains perhaps 5 rows, one for each company. I need to move ONE row from that table, along with all data directly or indirectly related to that row.

Comment: how are you going to save it if you move i mean insert

Comment: I need to save it in a different database with the same database design (but possibly with other existing data)

Comment: The safest and easiest way you can use is import/export, or using visual studio data base project, but by writing your own linq queries

Comment: @YavgenyP: Could you elaborate on that approach? How would a Visual Studio Database project work for this purpose?

Comment: @NielsBrinch you can check out [this tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833273.aspx). It explains hwo to compare two dbs and update one of them with the data from the other. Its a nice feature, though it might be not usefull if you dont have the required version of visual studio, or your two different data bases are nto accessible from a single machine. Even if thisi s not availibale to you, i think it'll still be easier to use the import/export tools of sql server to move the data, instead of writing c# code.

Comment: @YavgenyP: Are you aware that I need to just move a SLICE of data. See the "note" I added to my question, that highlights this point. Does your approach work with that? (The point being, I need to move SPECIFIC data from the database)

Comment: you can do this via the db project, yes. eventually you can select there exactly what you want to copy.

Comment: You are right that it's an issue I don't have Visual Studio Premium or Ultimate. Also, I'm searching for the quick fix that I hope I can get from the fact that I already have Entity Framework and that it ALREADY knows which entities are connected to what. Theoretically I should be able to select the specific Company I want to to transfer, and then simply generically include everything else.

Comment: @NielsBrinch I know this question is a little old, but what did you decide as your solution?

Comment: I cannot remember for sure, but I do not think I ever found a solution I was happy with and abandoned this idea. Of course, I could always hand code this in LINQ and get it to work and it wouldn't be a bad idea. But in this question I was looking for a more generic idea.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want to copy data from from a detailsview(tableName=Jobs) to another table(tablename=Company)

```
string apply = "INSERT INTO Company (JobTitle,CompanyName) select JobTitle,CompanyName from Jobs";
```

this is just an idea hope it help.

**UPDATE :**

So this will help you

[MSDN - Multiple Bulk Copy Operations (ADO.NET)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s4s223c6.aspx)

[With example](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/BulckCopyAdoNet2008192005135138PM/BulckCopyAdoNet20.aspx)

Comment: Sunny, I'm afraid I hadn't made my question sufficiently clear. I have rehprased a few details and hope it's more clear now.

Comment: It doesn't seem like that approach would be compile safe.

Comment: Yes but this is basic idea you can implement your checks there

Comment: It would still be possible to compile after I change a column name in my database, but it would fail in runtime...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12231/discussion-between-sunny-and-niels-brinch)